# On double click change the name of checkbox present in listbox as item template WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have bound the listbox with checkbox in it.

Now I have to change the name of checkbox on double clicking on it.

How can I change the name of checkbox
(I have to give option to user to change the name of checkbox means user will double click on name of checkbox then name will be replaced by textbox then user can add the name . On blur or suitable event it will be saved to database)

```
 <ListBox AlternationCount="2"   Width="140" Margin="18,63,480,24" Name="lstbxCuisines" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox  Name="chkCuisine" Height="20"  Margin="0,5,0,0" FontSize="12" Tag="{Binding CuisineId}" Content="{Binding Cuisine}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffffff"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f1f6fe"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I think the issue is your xaml file is completely blank.

Comment: Please check my xaml code

Answer (score 0):

You could add an MouseDoubleClick-Event to your ComboBox:

```
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Name="chkCuisine" Height="20"  Margin="0,5,0,0" FontSize="12" Tag="{Binding CuisineId}" Content="{Binding Cuisine}" MouseDoubleClick="chkCuisine_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            </DataTemplate>
```

In your Eventhandler, you can change the `Name` like so:

```
    private void chkCuisine_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ComboBox)sender).Name = "NewName";
    }
```

Comment: I have to give option to user to change the name of checkbox means user will double click on name of checkbox then name will be replaced by textbox then user can add the name . On blur or suitable event it will be saved to database

Answer (score 0):

1 way

```
<CheckBox.Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="CheckBoxDoubleClick"></EventSetter>
</Style>
```

```
protected void CheckBoxDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = e.Source as CheckBox;
        if (chk != null)
        {
            chk.Content = "Content Changed";
        }
    }
```

other way

```
<ListBox MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick">

private void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var chk = FindParentControl<CheckBox>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
        if (chk != null)
        {
            ((CheckBox)chk).Content = "Content Changed";
        }
    }

private DependencyObject FindParentControl<T>(DependencyObject control)
    {
        if (control == null)
            return null;

        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(control);
        while (parent != null && !(parent is T))
        {
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }

        return parent;
    }
```

Comment: please see my above answer's comment